# Importing asp.net core project from Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have started working on **ASP.Net Core** project against .**NET framework(452)** in visual studio 2017. My license expired and I need to switch to V**isual Studio Code**.
I am wondering what steps do I need to do in order to import it correctly and be able to debug it in browser. I have searched for answers all over the stack but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Why not just use VS 2017 Community Edition?

Comment: Long story short, I am working on company's laptop and this is student project, every license on this machine must be enterprise.

Comment: Remember visual studio code is a very low level IDE. Its nothing compared to VS

Comment: I know, but so far its my only way out. At least untill I get new license.

Comment: Technically, there shouldn't be any issue. You should be able to install VS code, start the csproj from VS code and be all set, debugging and all. It will involve a learning curve though till you understand how code UI works.